# Get date cell in excel that is at least n days older than the newest date entry

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

If I have a column with dates and a column with data. How do you go e.g. 10 days back in time (since the newest date entry (alwasy the last in the column)) in the date column to get the cell address in the corresponding data column? The data column is ordered. However, not all dates are within the list (it does usually not include weekends). That is why I need it to be at least 10 days and not exactly 10 days.

The reason why I ask is because I would like to calculate the average data value relating to approximately the last 10 days. Therefore, I need the cell range, which I find hard to get based on the data :(

The sheet could be looking like this:

```
08-09-2015  7,40
09-09-2015  7,40
10-09-2015  7,65
11-09-2015  7,15
14-09-2015  7,81
15-09-2015  7,40
16-09-2015  7,60
17-09-2015  7,90
18-09-2015  6,45
21-09-2015  7,90
22-09-2015  6,40
23-09-2015  7,57
24-09-2015  7,85
25-09-2015  7,70
28-09-2015  7,53
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. Feel free to give other suggestions as I am still pretty new to working like this in excel. The result was to use this equation:

```
=SUMIFS(C8:C1048576;B8:B1048576;">"&(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COUNTA(C8:C1048576)+7;2)))-10)/COUNTIF(B8:B1048576;">"&(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(COUNTA(C8:C1048576)+7;2)))-10)
```

**Short explanations of some of the data in the equation**

- My data goes from C8 to the buttom
- My dataes are given from B8 to the buttom
- This example counts 10 days back

I came to the solution with inspiration of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8842417/excel-formula-calculating-the-sum-of-a-column-for-the-last-7-days-from-today-as